# Continue counting serial number affer page on pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-4

I am displaying data results from database with php, ajax and jquery.
I have used codeigniter 4  pager library for pagination. But when I click the next page of pagination the serial number reset and start again from 1-10, all I want is when i click the next page to continue counting a serial number from 11-20, 21-30 etc...
Help please. Thank you.

//html table

```
   <table>
          <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>No.</th>
                     <th>MyColumn</th>
                 </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="result"></tbody>
   </table>
```

//jquery
show();

```
  function show(){
        let ajax = $.ajax({
             url     : '/Controller/getAll',
             method  : 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             cache   : false
      });
      ajax.done(function(data){
          let serialNumber = 1;

          $.each(data.result, function(k, v){
                html += `<tr>
                             <td>${serialNumber}</td>
                             <td>${v.myColums}</td>
                         </tr>`;
                serialNumber++;
          });
      });

      $('.result').html(html);
  }
```

// php controller

```
    public function getAll()
    {
        $result = $this->model->getData()->asObject()->paginate('10');
        $pager = $this->model->pager;
        
        foreach($result as $row){
            $output[] = [
                 'id'          =>  $row->id,
                 'myColumn'    =>  $row->myColumn,
            ];
        }

        $jsonArray = [
            'result'  => $output, 
            'pager'   => $pager->links(),
        ];
        return $this->response->setJSON($jsonArray);
    }
```

Comment: Every time you clicked the next page button, an ajax request is sent and therefore in ajax.done method your **serialNumber** variable starts from 1 again. But if you declare the **serialNumber** variable outside of the function scope your variable should increment in every step instead of reset itself from 1 again.

Comment: Why do you have a js defined "serialNumber"?   What does it *mean*?  What use is it?  What's it used for?   Looks like it should be something stored in the db, eg `${v.id}`

Comment: No,  i didn't display id from db all I want is serial number. ${v.id} will be added and other columns according to my need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would only answer the wrong half of the question?  ok, so you don't want v.id - but still:  *Why do you have a js defined "serialNumber"?* What does it mean? What use is it? What's it used for?

Comment: SerialNumber and ${v.id} are different since ${v.id} represent data id of primary key from database but I didn't what it to be displayed on the page. If I want it, the table ID column will be added later.

Comment: But what *is* SerialNumber meant to be?  It doesn't have any relation to your data and just seems a sequential/random number.  Do you mean it to be the row *index*?

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted, but I have a problem when click on next and previous pagination the serial increases even if it was the first page of pagination. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `serialNumber` when you receive a ajax response. Do it on page load.

```
 function show(){
    let ajax = $.ajax({
         url     : '/Controller/method',
         method  : 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache   : false
  });
  
  ajax.done(function(data){
      let serialNumber = 1; // move this to page load
      $.each(data.result, function(k, v){
            html += `<tr>
                         <td>${serialNumber}</td>
                         <td>${v.myColums}</td>
                     </tr>`;
            serialNumber++;
      });
  });

  $('.result').html(html);
}
```

Comment: This alone would be 1-10 on page 1, 11-20 on page 2, then if they click back to page 1, it wouldn't be 1-10, it would be 21-30 on page 1

Comment: Yes, I get that problem, How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside of the function

```
let serialNumber = 1;

function show(){
    let ajax = $.ajax({
        url     : '/Controller/getAll',
        method  : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache   : false
    });
    
    ajax.done(function(data){
        $.each(data.result, function(k, v){
            html += `<tr>
                         <td>${serialNumber}</td>
                         <td>${v.myColums}</td>
                     </tr>`;
            serialNumber++;
          });
    });
}
```

Another option is to return the page number from PHP and calculate the start point of the serial

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1;
$data["slno_start"] = (($page-1) * $config["per_page"]) + 1;
```